# Identify font for the logo of "Le Matin" newspaper

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typefaces

I am trying to find the fonts used in the following Logo for the Swiss newspaper "Le Matin". I've been trying to use whatthefont.com, but haven't had much success.

[image: Le Matin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By opening the image in Photoshop, reversing the colors, subtracting the shadow, and adding more tracking, I was able to upload it to WhatTheFont.com and come away with these results:

http://bit.ly/LeMatin-LogoFonts

I believe you are looking for **Glosa Headline Black**:

[image]

Comment: That's very similar but not quite the same. Perhaps they are using a custom derivative

Comment: @John, you're right - I didn't notice the curve of the bottom serifs... hmm...

Comment: @alisamii, you might want to try http://typophile.com/typeid to see if you can get an answer there.

Comment: `<pedantry>`Think you mean tracking, not leading?`</pedantry>`

Comment: What ever do you mean, user568458? ... :P ... (as I edit my answer)

Comment: @joshmax The link has expired!